# Jquery Validation has prevented my contact form from loading confirmation page even when all fields are valid

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am new to jquery and php and have been having difficulties trying to add jquery validation followed by php server-side validation to a contact form on a website I am working on.

I have Jquery validate.js embedded in the page and **the validation works fine but the problem is when the form is correctly filled out and all fields are valid.  The submit button does not continue to my next page.** A page that displays a confirmation message and some of the data from the form for clarification.

I have seen numerous tutorials and questions about using jquery validation and php with the desired result of submitting data to an email address without having to refresh or go to another page.  But have not found a simple way of making this work in a new loaded page.

before I added client-side jquery validation the form submitted fine.  It seems the validation is stopping it from continuing although an email is still sent to my email address as requested by the nextStep.php page but the page is not shown.  When javascript is disabled the submit button works.

I like how easy the validate.js makes customising the rules and error messages so if possible would prefer to use this method over other javascript coding methods.

Below is the code for both the contactForm.php and nextStep.php.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**'contactFrom.php'**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><head>

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="WJzOl7qm8SHqmzMTjrdQwqVgXRu-EUMnY3qYUdrcJhI" />
<meta name="keywords" content=" " />
<meta name=" " content=" " />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Custom Contact From</title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#contactForm').submit(function() {
 return $('#contactForm').valid();
 });
  $("#contactForm").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {
    firstName: "required",

    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    }
   },
   messages: {
    firstName: "Please enter your name.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
   }
  });
 });

</script>

<style type="text/css">

h1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

label, input[type=submit] {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

 label.error {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #F60;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 380px;
    text-align: right;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-weight: normal;
 }
.result {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
#contactForm {
    margin: 20px;
    width:  360px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
input[type=text], textarea {
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

</style>



</head>




<div id="wrapper">      


<form class="contactForm" action="nextStep.php" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">

      <h1>Contact Form</h1>



<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>

<br>

<input name="firstName" type="text" value="" id="firstName" class="required"/>

<br><br>

<label for="surname">Surname:</label>

<br>

<input name="surname" type="text" value="" id="surname" class="required"/>

<br><br>


<label for="email">Email:</label>

<br>

<input name="email" type="text" value="" id="email" class="required email" />

<br><br>


<label for="phone">Telephone Number:</label>

<br>

<input name="phone" type="text" value="" id="phone" class="required" />


<br><br>

<label for="comments">Comments:</label>

<br>

<textarea name="comments" class="required" cols="40" rows="10" id="requirements"></textarea>
<br><br>



<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>

</div> <!-- end of wrapper Div.-->


</body>

</html>
```

**'nextStep.php'** - This is the page that needs to load after both sets of validation and only currently loads with javascript disabled.  I have used formtoemail.com's code for the free version of a form to email contact form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Contact Form - Complete (Next Step)</title>

<style type="text/css">

h1, p  {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#formComplete {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>





<?php

/* Email address for form data to be sent to */

$my_email = "contact@email.co.uk";

/* Page to return to after the form has been completed and confirmation page displayed. */

$continue = "index.php";


$errors = array();

// Server-side validation:

// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.

if(count($_COOKIE)){foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value){unset($_REQUEST[$value]);}}

// Check all fields for an email header.

function recursive_array_check_header($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\n+|\r+)(content-type:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i",$element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_header($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_header($_REQUEST);

if($set){$errors[] = "You cannot send an email header.";}

unset($set);

// Validate email field.

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']))
{

if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\n+|\r+|:)/i",$_REQUEST['email'])){$errors[] = "Email address may not contain a new line or a colon.";}

$_REQUEST['email'] = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

if(substr_count($_REQUEST['email'],"@") != 1 || stristr($_REQUEST['email']," ")){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_email = explode("@",$_REQUEST['email']);if(empty($exploded_email[0]) || strlen($exploded_email[0]) > 64 || empty($exploded_email[1])){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{if(substr_count($exploded_email[1],".") == 0){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_domain = explode(".",$exploded_email[1]);if(in_array("",$exploded_domain)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{foreach($exploded_domain as $value){if(strlen($value) > 63 || !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i',$value)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid"; break;}}}}}}

}

// Check referrer is from same site.

if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))){$errors[] = "You must enable referrer logging to use the form.";}

// Check for a blank form.

function recursive_array_check_blank($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(!empty($element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_blank($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_blank($_REQUEST);

if(!$set){$errors[] = "You cannot send a blank form. " ;}

unset($set);

// Display any errors and exit if errors exist.

if(count($errors)){foreach($errors as $value){print "$value<br>";} exit;}

if(!defined("PHP_EOL")){define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");}

// Build message.

function build_message($request_input){if(!isset($message_output)){$message_output ="";}if(!is_array($request_input)){$message_output = $request_input;}else{foreach($request_input as $key => $value){if(!empty($value)){if(!is_numeric($key)){$message_output .= str_replace("_"," ",ucfirst($key)).": ".build_message($value).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;}else{$message_output .= build_message($value).", ";}}}}return rtrim($message_output,", ");}

$message = build_message($_REQUEST);

$message = $message . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."-- ".PHP_EOL."";

$message = stripslashes($message);

$subject = "FormToEmail Comments";

$headers = "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'];

mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>



<div id="wrapper">

<div id="formComplete">





      <h1>Thank you for your comments we will get back to you very soon<?php print stripslashes($_REQUEST['FirstName']); ?>.</b></h1>

          <br>

    <p><a href="<?php print $continue; ?>">Return to home page.</a></p>



</div><!-- end #formComplete -->

</div><!-- end #Wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an empty [submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

}
```

Take that out.

Comment: you were right and thats all it was.  Thanks very much sachleen